# (Canonical) Partition function - what assumption is at work here?

Tags: statistical-mechanics

The canonical partition function is defined as $$Z=\sum_{s}e^{-\beta E_s}$$ with the sum being over all states of the system. The way I saw this derived was by assuming that for each state, the probability of the system occupying that state is proportional to the Boltzmann factor: $P(E=E_s) = c \cdot e^{-\beta E_s}$. Summing the probabilities to one gives $Z=\frac{1}{c}$.

My question is : What principles were used in order to get this probability distribution for the energy?

Comment: This might be very similar to [that question](http://physics.stackexchange.com/questions/61936/why-does-the-boltzmann-factor-e-e-kt-seem-to-imply-that-lower-energies-are/61984#61984). Please edit your question if the mentioned thread is not enough.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

My favorite way to obtain the canonical partition function is via quantum statistical mechanics and involves essentially only one principle: **maximum entropy**.  The principle says that to obtain the statistical state of a system in a certain ensemble, one extremizes the entropy subject to the constraints that define the ensemble.

In the context of quantum statistical mechanics for a system in the canonical ensemble, one extremizes the so-called von-Neumann entropy
$$
  S_\mathrm{vn}(\rho) = -k\,\mathrm{tr}(\rho\ln\rho)
$$
subject to the constraint that the ensemble average energy has some fixed value $E$;
$$
  \mathrm{tr}(\rho H) = E
$$
Here $\rho$ denotes the density operator of the system, and $H$ is its Hamiltonian.  This constraint is, in fact, one way of *defining* the canonical ensemble.  This is a constrained optimization problem that can be solved using the method of Lagrange multipliers.  The result is that the density operator of the system is.
$$
  \rho = \frac{1}{Z}e^{-\beta H}, \qquad Z = \mathrm{tr}(e^{-\beta H})
$$
where $\beta$ is the Lagrange multiplier corrsponding to the constraint of fixed ensemble average energy.

**Important Digression.**  If you use the derivation above, it's not at all clear a priori why the multiplier $\beta$ is inverse temperature.  The multiplier $\beta$ can be identified with inverse temperature using the following argument.  Notice that for $\rho$ of the canonical ensemble, we have
\begin{align}
  S_\mathrm{vn}(\rho) 
&= -k\mathrm{tr}\left(\rho\ln \frac{e^{-\beta H}}{Z}\right)\\
&= -k\mathrm{tr}\left(\rho(\ln e^{-\beta H}-\ln Z)\right)\\
&=k\mathrm{tr}\left(\rho(\beta H+\ln Z)\right)\\
&= k(\beta \mathrm{tr}(\rho H) + \ln Z)\\
&= k(\beta E + \ln Z)
\end{align}
Now, notice that the Lagrange multiplier is actually a function of $E$, the constrained value of the ensemble average of $H$, so we have
$$
  \frac{\partial S_\mathrm{vn}}{\partial E} =  k\left(\beta ' E + \beta + \frac{1}{Z}\frac{\partial Z}{\partial E}\right)
$$
where $\beta'$ denotes the derivative of $\beta$ with respect to $E$, but
\begin{align}
  \frac{1}{Z}\frac{\partial Z}{\partial E} 
&= \frac{1}{Z}\frac{\partial}{\partial E} \mathrm{tr}(e^{-\beta H})
= \mathrm{tr}(-\beta'He^{-\beta H}/Z)
= -\beta'\mathrm{tr}(\rho H)
= -\beta' E
\end{align}
so that putting this all together, we get
$$
  \frac{\partial S_\mathrm{vn}}{\partial E} = k\beta
$$
on the other hand, recall that the thermodynamic temperature satisfies
$$
  \frac{1}{T} = \frac{\partial S}{\partial E}
$$
so that if we identify the von-Neumann entropy with the thermodynamic entropy ($S = S_\mathrm{vn}$) gives
$$
  \beta = \frac{1}{kT}
$$
as desired.

Answer (score 4):

In canonical ensemble, you have a heat reservoir ($L$) and the observed system ($l$).
The total energy is $E_{tot} = E_L +E_l$, and is a constant because the total system $(L+ l)$ is isolated.

The probability $p_l$ of finding the observed system in a microscopic state of energy $E_l$ is equal to the probability of finding the heat reservoir in a microscopic state of energy $E_L$, that is :

$$p_l = \frac{\Omega_L(E_L)}{\Omega_{TOT}}$$
where $\Omega_L(E_L)$ is the number of microscopic states for the heat reservoir, and $\Omega_{TOT}$  is the number of microscopic states for the total system  $(L+ l)$.

Now, by definition the entropy $S_L(E_L) = k \ln \Omega_L(E_L)$.

Because $E_l = (E_{TOT} - E_L) << {E_{TOT}}$, we can write :

$S_L(E_L) = S_L(E_{TOT}) + (E_L - E_{TOT} ) \frac{\partial S}{\partial E}$

By definition of the temperature, we have : $\frac{\partial S}{\partial E} = \frac{1}{T}$

So : $S_L(E_L) = S_L(E_{TOT}) + (E_L - E_{TOT} ) \frac{1}{T} = S_L(E_{TOT})  -  \large \frac{E_l}{T}$

So we have  :

$$ln (p_l) = ln (\Omega_L(E_L)) - ln (\Omega_{TOT}) = \frac{S_L(E_L)}{k} - ln (\Omega_{TOT})$$
That is : 
$$ln (p_l) =  \frac{ - E_l}{k T}  + \frac{S_L(E_{TOT})}{k}- ln (\Omega_{TOT})$$

The last two terms are constant, so we could write, taking the exponential :

$$p_l = A e^{\large \frac{ \large - E_l}{k T}}$$